# Is there a way to know which Hard Drive MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData is returning results about?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, hard-drive, wmi-query

I'm using WMI to query information about a computer's hard drives, among other things, but I'm having trouble working with the information I'm getting, take this WMI query for example:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcherDisk = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData");
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcherDisk.Get())
{
   byte[] arrVendorSpecific = (byte[])queryObj.GetPropertyValue("VendorSpecific");
   ...
}
```

Using that I can get all the SMART information for each hard drive on my PC, however, and since there's no sorting function for WMI queries as far as I know, I'm having trouble with that query returning information in an inverse order as this one, which gets other data also regarding hard drives:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{    
     ...
}
```

Say the result is:

```
# HD | Value
 HD1 | Val2
 HD2 | Val1
```

If I was certain the order would always be inverse perhaps I could just fix that by matching them, but since I can't know that as far as I know, I have tried to use the `Win32_DiskDrive` `Index` value which returns an index value for every hard drive in the pc, however I haven't found a way to do the same with the `MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData` query, what would you say are my options here?

By the way, I **know** my information is wrong because I have been using AIDA64 software to compare my results.